# How can DataGrid String column format be changed dynamically at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My WPF desktop application provides a UI to search persons and show the results in a DataGrid.
In addition the user can change the language (Current(UI)Culture) at runtime.

The DataGrid definition in XAML is

```
<DataGrid Name="SearchResultTable" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinHeight="200" CanUserSortColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="lastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}" SortDirection="Ascending" IsReadOnly="True" DisplayIndex="0"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="firstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"   IsReadOnly="True" DisplayIndex="1"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="dateOfBirth" Binding="{Binding DateOfBirth }"   IsReadOnly="True" DisplayIndex="2"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The DateOfBirth column content should be formatted depending on the selected language.
c# code part is:

```
DataGridTextColumn col = (DataGridTextColumn)SearchResultTable.Columns[2];
col.Binding.StringFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

This code part is executed after the UI class has been created and each time when the user selects a different language.
This works fines as long as the user did not execute a search which populates the DataGrid.

But once the DataGrid is populated the first time per

```
IList<Person> searchResult = // read data from database
SearchResultTable.ItemsSource = searchResult;
```

and the user selects a different language the following exception is thrown:

```
Binding cannot be changed after it has been used
```

So, how can DataGrid String column format be changed dynamically at runtime ?

**EDIT**

With the answer of mm8 I could implement a solution as follows:
Since I may not change the Person class (Business domain!) I created a helper class that takes Person as reference

```
public class PersonHelper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
    private Person person = null;
    public String LastName { get => person.getLastName(); set => person.setLastName(LastName); }
    // ... 
    public string FormattedDateOfBirth => DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString();
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    // ...
}
```

in the UI class Search method:

```
PersonObsColl = new ObservableCollection<PersonHelper>();
foreach (Person p in searchResult)
{
    PersonHelper ph = new PersonHelper(p);
    ph.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyFormattedDateOfBirthChanged);
    PersonObsColl.Add(ph);
}
```

in the UI class method that is called when the CurrentUICulture changes

```
foreach (PersonHelper ph in PersonObsColl)
    ph.OnPropertyChanged("FormattedDateOfBirth");
```

and the Handler in the UI class

```
private void PropertyFormattedDateOfBirthChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is PersonHelper && e.PropertyName.Equals("FormattedDateOfBirth"))
    {
        // avoid to call invalidation for every search result line; can this be improved ?
        if(PersonObsColl.IndexOf((PersonHelper)sender) == PersonObsColl.Count -1)
            SearchResultTable.InvalidateVisual();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you define the string format as ` <DataGridTextColumn Header="dateOfBirth" Binding="{Binding DateOfBirth,StringFormat={x:Static CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern}}"   IsReadOnly="True" DisplayIndex="2"/>`?

Comment: The XAML compiles with errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can DataGrid String column format be changed dynamically at runtime?

It can't. You can't change the `StringFormat` of any existing binding.

Instead of setting the `StringFormat` property of the column, you should bind to a property that returns the already formatted string and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for this one whenever the format changes:

```
public string FormattedDateOfBirth => DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString();
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="dateOfBirth" Binding="{Binding FormattedDateOfBirth}" IsReadOnly="True" DisplayIndex="2"/>
```

> With this answer, the capability to allow the user to sort the respective column BY DATE is lost (it is sorted by string rules instead).

That's just a matter of setting the `SortMemberPath` property to the name of the original property:

```
<DataGridTextColumn ... SortMemberPath="DateOfBirth" Binding="{Binding FormattedDateOfBirth}" />
```

Comment: Works! Thank you! I will edit my post to show how I did it, may be you know how it can be improved

Answer (score -1):

With the first answer, the capability to allow the user to sort the respective column BY DATE is lost (it is sorted by string rules instead).

In order to keep the sort by date capability I finally ended up by replacing the column at runtime whenever the CurrentUICulture changes:

```
foreach (DataGridColumn dgc in SearchResultTable.Columns)
{
    if (dgc is DataGridTextColumn)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn dgtc = (DataGridTextColumn)dgc;
        Binding bo = (Binding)dgtc.Binding;
        string pps = bo.Path.Path;
        if (pps.Equals("DateOfBirth"))
        {
            int idx = SearchResultTable.Columns.IndexOf(dgtc);
            DataGridTextColumn dgtcn = new DataGridTextColumn();
            dgtcn.IsReadOnly = true;
            Binding b = new Binding("DateOfBirth");
            b.StringFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
            dgtcn.Binding = b;
            SearchResultTable.Columns[idx] = dgtcn;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the `SortMemberPath` property of the column to the name of the original property instead. I edited my answer to clarify this. This solution unnecessarily creates a new column and a new binding.

Comment: Uhhh! I should have RTFM more thoroughly. Thanks again!