# WPF-DataGrid: how can a sort by date be established without loosing the localized date format for presentation?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

This is a follow up question to the answer given for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926340/how-can-datagrid-string-column-format-be-changed-dynamically-at-runtime) which suits well for the presentation of dates in localized format.

But with the proposed solution (`public string FormattedDateOfBirth => DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString();`) the possibility for the user to sort that column BY DATE is lost, i.e. the DataGrid is sorted by string sorting rules and not by date sorting rules.

So, how can a sort by date be re-established without loosing the localized date format for presentation ?

Comment: Forget this question everything is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926340/how-can-datagrid-string-column-format-be-changed-dynamically-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply format the `DataGrid` column, it could look something like:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="DOB" Binding="{Binding DateOfBirth,StringFormat=MM/dd/yyy}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: In the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926340/how-can-datagrid-string-column-format-be-changed-dynamically-at-runtime) I learned that `Binding.StringFormat`cannot be changed dynamically (depending on changing `CurrentUICulture*).